# Goal: package in maven . what does this mean

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to maven and I am porting a java project to a maven project . I installed the maven plugin and set up the environment . the steps I followed are

1) Used the inbuild convert to maven option in eclipse
2) updated my POM with all the repo info and dependency info

when I try and run my maven project it asks me to enter my goal . I read on SO that I am supposed to enter package . I am not sure what this all means , a lot of googling later I am still not able to understand what this really means . Is this converting my project to a jar ??

Comment: This is not the place to give you a basic Maven tutorial... Read [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/) and the [Sonatype books](http://www.sonatype.com/resources/books) that you can find online.

Comment: You need to provide exact command lines and error messages you're using. That said my guess is you're running just `mvn`, which does nothing. You need to tell Maven what to do. Most commonly you'll want `mvn compile` (to just rebuild classes), `mvn package` (to create JARs`), or `mvn install` (creates JARs and puts them into your local repository, usually necessary for multimodule projects.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should place all your compiled class files into a jar as well as anything located in your `src/main/resources` folder. Once you start configuring other plugins in the `<build>` portion of your pom, then `package` may behave differently and produce something else such as an ejb, war or ear.

You should take a look at the maven page on the [Build Lifecycles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Also, as Jesper said, this isn't really the place for such a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Default lifecycle has the following build phases (for a complete list of the build phases, refer to the [Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)):

- **validate** - validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available
- **compile** - compile the source code of the project
- **test** - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed
- **package** - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
- **integration-test** - process and deploy the package if necessary into an environment where  integration tests can be run
- **verify** - run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria
- **install** - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
- **deploy** - done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for  sharing with other developers and projects.